# Make Marker movable with one touch on Google Map V2?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any way to make the marker touchable and movable with one click  (not draggable) on Google Map V2 ?

I mean when I touch it , make it movable in any position i want to on the map.

what modification on code??

```
Googlemap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                String msg = marker.getTitle() + " ("
                        + marker.getPosition().latitude +    ","
                        + marker.getPosition().longitude + ")";
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    return (Googlemap != null);
}

Googlemap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);
            List<Address> list = null;
            LatLng latlng = marker.getPosition();

            try {
                list = gc.getFromLocation(latlng.latitude,
                        latlng.longitude, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            Address add = list.get(0);
            marker.setTitle(add.getLocality());
            marker.setSnippet(add.getCountryName());

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you have more than one markers on the map?

Comment: No, i have one marker only

Comment: So you will touch on the marker and then touch anywhere else on the map. Then the marker should move to that position. Isn't it?

Comment: yup sir , this is what i mean

Answer (score 0):

So you have a marker on your `GoogleMap`(nothing else like polylines/polygons). And if you have an object `map` for `GoogleMap`.

Suppose you have a global variable `boolean change=false`
Now, when you touch on the marker,

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                change=true;
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Now, check it inside mapClickListener

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {

                     if(arg0!=null && change){
                         change=false;
                          //clear map
                         map.clear(); 
                            // create marker
                             MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(arg0);

                             // Changing marker icon
                             marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker));

                             // adding marker
                             map.addMarker(marker);
                             }
                }
            });
```

If you have another markers or lines, dont use `map.clear()`. Change the values of corresponding marker only.

Comment: no action happened.thanks 4 your trial . i will send u the project file